# foreign key constraint error while deleting from table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:

Requests - Request_id , Request_Message; // contains Requests

Responses - Response_id , Request_id , Response_Message; // Contains Responses for the request..
Request_id is foreign key for this table

Now while i am running the query **delete from requests where Request_id = "REQ001";..**.. if there is no corresponding response in responses table then query is working fine, other its giving foreign key constraint  error.

I want while i delete any request from requests table all its corresponding responses must delete automatically from response table.. How to achieve this??

Thanks for your time..

Devesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `CASCADE` in the definition of the `FOREIGN KEY` constraint is an option. However, I recommend using the multiple-table syntax of the delete statement, e.g.:

```
DELETE FROM Requests, Responses
USING Requests
LEFT JOIN Responses ON Requests.Request_id=Responses.Request_id
WHERE Requests.Request_id='REQ001';
```

This is my preferred solution because it makes more explicit what actually happens.

Answer (score 2):

try using cascade on delete:

```
create table Responses(
...
CONSTRAINT fk_column
  FOREIGN KEY (Request_id)
  REFERENCES Requests (Request_id)
  ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Cascade Delete while defining child table (which will have foreign key) structure.

```
CREATE TABLE `Responses ` 
  ( 
     `Request_id` INT(10), 
     INDEX (Request_id), 
     FOREIGN KEY (Request_id) REFERENCES Requests (Request_id) ON DELETE CASCADE 
  )
```

Just remember that you need to use the InnoDB storage engine: the default MyISAM storage engine doesn't support foreign keys.

Comment: shouldn't the foreign key definition be on the child table "Responses"?

Answer (score 0):

You need to either delete first all `Responses` records referring to the `Request_id` you're deleting, or you need to define your foreign keys as `ON DELETE CASCADE`.

Answer (score 0):

As described in the MySQL manual for `FOREIGN KEY` constraints, http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html, if you want to let the database handle this instead of your application, you have to change your `CONSTRAINT` to something like:

```
CONSTRAINT my_constraint FOREIGN KEY request_id (request_id) REFERENCES Requests (request_id) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

The `ON DELETE CASCADE` part will take care of deleting and records in the `Responses` table that have their `request_id` set to the same value as a record being deleted in the `Requests` table.